# 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in for loop

Tags: python, string

So I want to extract gps coordinates from a column in a Pandas DataFrame, single command line works perfect as here, for example, with 6 can be replaced to any other integers:

```
Input: crimedata['GEOLOCATION'][6][-12:-1]
Output: '(30.42437, -91.051507'
```

Once I get the coord strings out of the bulk string, then I can edit it more to precisely what I want, so I wrote a for loop to extract gps coordinates from 320904 lines of strings,

```
lat_coord=[]
long_coord=[]
for i in range(0, 320904):
    lat_coord.append(crimedata['GEOLOCATION'][i][-22:-13])
    long_coord.append(crimedata['GEOLOCATION'][i][-12:-1])

print lat_coord, long_coord
```

And I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

It looks like it is the [i] causing trouble, but I don't know how to fix it. I'd appreciate any inputs. Many thanks!

Here is the structure of the column that contains the strings I want to extract gps coordinnates from:

```
0         7234 AIRLINE HW\nBATON ROUGE, LA\n(30.482565, ...
1         5900 PEERLESS ST\nBATON ROUGE, LA\n(30.516849,...
2         10250 PLAZA AMERICANA DR\nBATON ROUGE, LA 7081...
3         964 N 48TH\nBATON ROUGE, LA 70802\n(30.457107,...
4         5950 ST GERARD AV\nBATON ROUGE, LA 70805\n(30....
5         11111 COURSEY BL\nBATON ROUGE, LA 70816\n(30.4...
6         3121 S SHERWOOD FOREST BL\nBATON ROUGE, LA\n(3...
7         2520 PLANK RD\nBATON ROUGE, LA 70805\n(30.4705...
8         4414 TUPELLO ST\nBATON ROUGE, LA 70808\n(30.41...
.....
320904    1253 FLORIDA ST\nBATON ROUGE, LA 70802\n(30.44...

Name: GEOLOCATION, dtype: object
```

Comment: We need to see the structure of `crimedata`.

Comment: Dudeeeeeeeeeee......no. Put that table and edit it into your post. And put it in proper format too, please.

Comment: Aww i am trying sorry!

Comment: string escapes don't work in comments. if this is a table, you can use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to generate ascii tables

Comment: Can you also include the full stack trace? Have you tried debugging this at all, for instance, does this happen on the first index `i` or on some other `i`? Which `i`? Are you sure your data is well-formed? etc

Comment: The column structure added into the original post. Though not as a table format. It was edited in a way that could represent the column structure in the file, with first column as the index column, and the second column as the string column (dtype = object).

Comment: @pvg I spot checked several i numbers (like 1, 2, 6, ... etc) and it worked. But when I ran the for loop, it always gives me the float __getitem__ error. I am going to debug more to see which i I can get to (lol, there are 320904 items in the list).

Comment: you can just check if the dereferenced item is a float first and then print the float and the index. Make the computer do the work, don't 'spot check'.

Comment: Thanks all for the inputs. Right now testing and there is a hole at i=90090 (with some help), I guess I need to continue find out all the holes in the rest of the list.

Comment: [Catch the Exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and in the except suite print relavent variables, calc results, condition results, ...

Comment: @wwii thanks for the suggestions, reading document now :)